# How to drop all rows that don't contain A in this DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Dataframe:

```
           C_M       C_N     C_Y
 0         100       A        A
 1         200       C        A,D                 
 2         300       B        A,C,E
 3         400       A        B,C,A
 4         500       A        A,D,E
```

How get I can I only keep the rows where the column `C_N` and column `C_Y` have "A"s?

This would be the desired outcome:

```
           C_M       C_N     C_Y
 0         100       A        A
 1         400       A        B,C,A
 2         500       A        A,D,E
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use boolean masking and then reset the index

```
# assuming your original DataFrame is named `df`
>>> df = df[(df.C_N == 'A') & (df.C_Y.str.contains('A'))].reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
   C_M C_N    C_Y
0  100   A      A
1  400   A  B,C,A
2  500   A  A,D,E
```

In case there could be values like `BA,C,D` in `C_Y` that you don't want to match, then you could use a regex as argument for [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df[(df.C_N == 'A') & (df.C_Y.str.contains(r'(?:^A$)|(?:^A,)|(?:,A,)|(?:,+A$)'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

The regex checks if it only contains an `A` (nothing else) or starts with an `A,` or contains an `,A,` or ends with an `,A`

Comment: I'm not that familiar with regexes so you might need to double check if it really does what I think it should do.

Answer (score 1):

To account for cases where column `C_Y` can contain compound letters (e.g. 'BA'), this solution splits that columns and ensures that the value `A` is contained as a unique element within the list:

```
>>> df.loc[(df['C_N'] == 'A') & (df['C_Y'].str.split(',').apply(lambda row: 'A' in row))]
   C_M C_N    C_Y
0  100   A      A
3  400   A  B,C,A
4  500   A  A,D,E
```

Per the sample data, it assumes no spacing in column `C_Y`.

Comment: Definitely one edge case that is worth considering. But `apply` on a `Series` is really slow...

Comment: Yes, it would be easier if the values in `C_Y` were known to be A-Z.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
In [1312]: df[(df.C_N == 'A') & (df.C_Y.str.contains('A'))]
Out[1312]:
   C_M C_N    C_Y
0  100   A      A
3  400   A  B,C,A
4  500   A  A,D,E
```

another

```
In [1317]: df[df[['C_N', 'C_Y']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A')).all(1)]
Out[1317]:
   C_M C_N    C_Y
0  100   A      A
3  400   A  B,C,A
4  500   A  A,D,E
```